# JavaScript create and remove "li" tags

Tags: javascript, html, forms

**Introduction**

Hello, I am trying to create a pizza form for my website. In this example I want customers to have the ability to create and remove any items they request.

**Problem**

The pizza form is almost fully functioning except the fact that the items which are added can not be removed. I am wishing for a way which the items can be removed on the side of the ordered item.

**Javascript**

```
var pizzas = [
    {name: "S - Pepperoni Pizza", price: "$4.99"},
    {name: "M - Pepperoni Pizza", price: "$5.15"},
    {name: 'L - Pepperoni Pizza', price: '$6.70'},
    {name: "S - Meat Lovers Pizza", price: "$4.99"},
    {name: "M - Meat Lovers Pizza", price: "$5.15"},
    {name: 'L - Meat Lovers Pizza', price: '$6.70'},
    {name: "S - Hawaiian Pizza", price: "$4.99"},
    {name: "M - Hawaiian Pizza", price: "$5.15"},
    {name: 'L - Hawaiian Pizza', price: '$6.70'},
];

function addPizza(index) {
    var pizza = pizzas[index];
    var name = pizza.name;
    var price = pizza.price;
    LISTname = document.createElement('li');
    LISTname.class = "item";
    LISTname.innerHTML = name;
    LISTprice = document.createElement('li');
    LISTprice.class = "price";
    LISTprice.innerHTML = price;
    document.getElementById("items").appendChild(LISTname);
    document.getElementById("price").appendChild(LISTprice);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="bill">
    <h2>Bill</h2>
    <ul id="items"></ul>
    <ul id="price"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is a professional project, I strongly suggest you look into a JavaScript Framework for this. Backbone or Angular are a good idea. They include templating and event support which is what you really want.

I suspect it's for homework though so good luck. Generally you won't get good answers for questions like this where you are expecting people to add functionality to a piece of your code though.

Comment: Hell I'd recommend just being able to use something like MooTools or jQuery to make your manipulations easier. If the form is almost fully functional, can we see the code/HTML required for it? The provided information doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it like you have it, the easiest way would be to remove items on click. You add an event listener that on click will remove the items you add to the list now:

```
function removeItem(listName, listPrice) {

var items = document.getElementById("items");
var prices = document.getElementById("price");

items.removeChild(listName);
prices.removeChild(listPrice);

}

var items = document.getElementById("items");
LISTname.addEventListener('click', function(){removeItem(LISTname, LISTprice)});
items.appendChild(LISTname); 

var prices = document.getElementById("price");
LISTprice.addEventListener('click', function(){removeItem(LISTname, LISTprice)});
prices.appendChild(LISTprice);
```

Answer (score 1):

As people said you may consider to use a library, but you may also simplify it like this;

```
LISTname.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}, false);
LISTprice.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}, false);

// or with named function
function removeItem() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}

LISTname.addEventListener('click', removeItem, false);
LISTprice.addEventListener('click', removeItem, false);
```

See more here about [`addEventListener`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

**TO FIX**

I suppose, you need to fix these;

- these are become global cos no `var` before
  `LISTname` and `LISTprice`
- these usage is incorrect
  not `LISTname.class` or `LISTprice.class`, should be `LISTname.className` and `LISTprice.className`

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check these out (but not tested :));

Procedural Style;

```
function createItem(content, attributes) {
    var item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    for (var key in attributes) {
        item.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]);
    }
    item.addEventListener("click", removeItem, false);
    return item;
}
function addItem(to, item) {
    document.getElementById(to).appendChild(item);
}
function removeItem(e) {
    e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
}
function addPizza(i) {
    var pizza = PIZZAS[i];
    if (!pizza) { 
        return alert("No pizza!"); 
    }
    addItem("items", createItem(pizza.name, {"className": "item"}));
    addItem("price", createItem(pizza.price, {"className": "price"}));
}
```

OOP Style;

```
function Pizza(pizzas) {
    this.pizzas = pizzas;
}

Pizza.prototype = {
    createItem: function(content, attributes) {
        var item = document.createElement("li");
        item.innerHTML = innerHTML;
        for (var key in attributes) {
            item.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]);
        }
        item.addEventListener("click", this.removeItem, false);
        return item;
    },
    addItem: function(to, item) {
        document.getElementById(to).appendChild(item);
    },
    removeItem: function(e) {
        e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
    },
    addPizza: function(i) {
        var pizza = this.pizzas[i];
        if (!pizza) { 
            return alert("No pizza!"); 
        }
        this.addItem("items", this.createItem(pizza.name, {"className": "item"}));
        this.addItem("price", this.createItem(pizza.price, {"className": "price"}));
    }
}

var pizza = new Pizza(PIZZAS);
pizza.addPizza(1);
```